How instruct postfix to avoid relay to my organisation's mail server when it could send it locally?
I have postfix on two linux machines in the same domain (only the last part of the IP's differ); call them A and B. They need to communicate with each other by email. Recently I had to relay mails destined outside through my organisation's campus mail server so that they get the SPF required by e.g. google/gmail. After adding to main.cf
relayhost = mail.*organisation.dom*:25

the relay is working well. But mails destined from A to B is now sent twice, once locally to A to A (!) and A to B via the relayhost. Worse yet, the mails started to repeat every few seconds and soon overcharged the relayhost. I had a look at
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relay_domains = $mydestination

However, destinations for outbound mail are hecatomb. Before I contemplate a different method to get the data from A to B (need to append files on B, ahem), is there a way to tell postfix to distinguish the routes on behalf of the recipient's addresses?
On machine A postfix version is 2.9.6
